# .NET Garbage Collector and JOB_OBJECT memory limits

Tags: .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, windows-container, memory-limit

I'm trying to understand whether .NET garbage collector and memory allocator respect limits defined in Windows [JOB_OBJECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-jobobject_extended_limit_information).
I'm especially interested in how this works in .NET Framework 4.8 but could not find any information in public documentation.

Comment: Yes, .NET runtime respects those limits.

Comment: @KonradKokosa, thanks for the reply. Do you know in what version it was introduced? The only information I found is that it was planned: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/job-support-in-the-gc/